# How can I find out how much memory is physically installed in Windows?

Tags: c++, memory, system

I need to log information about how much RAM the user has. My first approach was to use `GlobalMemoryStatusEx` but that only gives me how much memory is available to windows, not how much is installed. I found this function `GetPhysicallyInstalledSystemMemory` but its only Vista and later. I need this to work on XP. Is there a fairly simple way of querying the SMBIOS information that `GetPhysicallyInstalledSystemMemory` was using or is there a registry value somewhere that I can find this out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: I'd use steelbytes' answer, but if you can't use WMI For some reason, you can do this:

I don't believe Windows versions prior to Vista track this information -- you'd have to do some system specific BIOS or Motherboard enumeration to find the true value prior to Vista. Your best bet is to call the new API, `GetPhysicallyInstalledSystemMemory`, and fail over to `GlobalMemoryStatusEx` for XP systems.

Answer (score 5):

You should take a look at the [Win32_ComputerSystem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394102(VS.85).aspx) Class (WMI) and the TotalPhysicalMemory property. There are ways to access this information via .Net via the [System.Management](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.aspx) namespace for managed code (I use C#, so I haven't tried using visual studio for c++ development myself). You could also create a script to run WMI directly and have your c++ program call the script.

UPDATE: You may also look at the [Win32_PhysicalMemory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394347(VS.85).aspx) Class (take a look at the Capacity property). This will alleviate inaccurate readings due to the BIOS using some of the RAM etc.

UPDATE 2:

I've tried this in C# (3.5) and Windows XP (SP 2) and it works. I'm sure you can do something similar with the same WMI classes in C++ (at least through Visual Studio). It works no problem, so it's not a Vista or greater issue. I'm not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for, but this code will return the total physical memory capacity of the system (not how much is free). Hopefully this is what you meant. Anyway here is some sample code that locates each stick of RAM and displays some info about each one (including capacity) and then the total at the bottom:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Management;
using System.Text;

namespace WmiTest
{
    public class RamCounter
    {
        private List<RamStick> _ramSticks;
        private int _totalRam;
        private StringBuilder _stringRepresentation;

        public RamCounter()
        {
            _ramSticks = new List<RamStick>();
            _totalRam = 0;
            _stringRepresentation = new StringBuilder();
        }

        public void GetRamSticks()
        {
            _ramSticks.Clear();
            _totalRam = 0;

            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_PhysicalMemory");
            ManagementObjectCollection queryCollection = searcher.Get();

            foreach (ManagementObject mo in queryCollection)
            {
                _ramSticks.Add(
                    new RamStick(Convert.ToUInt64(mo.GetPropertyValue("Capacity")),
                                 mo.GetPropertyValue("DeviceLocator").ToString(),
                                 mo.GetPropertyValue("Description").ToString(),
                                 Convert.ToUInt32(mo.GetPropertyValue("FormFactor")),
                                 Convert.ToUInt32(mo.GetPropertyValue("Speed"))));
            }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            _stringRepresentation.Capacity = 0;

            foreach (RamStick rs in _ramSticks)
            {
                _stringRepresentation.Append(rs.ToString());
                _totalRam += rs.CapacityInMB;
            }

            _stringRepresentation.Append("Total RAM(MB): " + _totalRam);
            return _stringRepresentation.ToString();
        }
    }

    public class RamStick
    {
        private UInt64 _capacity;
        private UInt32 _formFactor;

        public RamStick(UInt64 capacity, string location, string description, UInt32 formFactor, UInt32 speed)
        {
            _capacity = capacity;
            Location = location;
            Description = description;
            _formFactor = formFactor;
            Speed = speed;
        }

        public int CapacityInMB
        {
            get { return Convert.ToInt32(_capacity / (1024 * 1024)); }
        }

        public string Location
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        public string Description
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        public string GetFormFactor()
        {
            string formFactor = string.Empty;

            switch (_formFactor)
            {
                case 1:
                    formFactor = "Other";
                    break;

                case 2:
                    formFactor = "SIP";
                    break;

                case 3:
                    formFactor = "DIP";
                    break;

                case 4:
                    formFactor = "ZIP";
                    break;

                case 5:
                    formFactor = "SOJ";
                    break;

                case 6:
                    formFactor = "Proprietary";
                    break;

                case 7:
                    formFactor = "SIMM";
                    break;

                case 8:
                    formFactor = "DIMM";
                    break;

                case 9:
                    formFactor = "TSOP";
                    break;

                case 10:
                    formFactor = "PGA";
                    break;

                case 11:
                    formFactor = "RIMM";
                    break;

                case 12:
                    formFactor = "SODIMM";
                    break;

                case 13:
                    formFactor = "SRIMM";
                    break;

                case 14:
                    formFactor = "SMD";
                    break;

                case 15:
                    formFactor = "SSMP";
                    break;

                case 16:
                    formFactor = "QFP";
                    break;

                case 17:
                    formFactor = "TQFP";
                    break;

                case 18:
                    formFactor = "SOIC";
                    break;

                case 19:
                    formFactor = "LCC";
                    break;

                case 20:
                    formFactor = "PLCC";
                    break;

                case 21:
                    formFactor = "BGA";
                    break;

                case 22:
                    formFactor = "FPBGA";
                    break;

                case 23:
                    formFactor = "LGA";
                    break;

                default:
                    formFactor = "Unknown";
                    break;
            }

            return formFactor;
        }

        public UInt32 Speed
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("Description:{1}{0}" 
                               + "Location:{2}{0}"
                               + "Form Factor:{3}{0}"
                               + "Speed:{4}{0}"
                               + "Capacity(MB):{5}{0}{0}",

                               Environment.NewLine,
                               Description,
                               Location,
                               GetFormFactor(),
                               Speed,
                               CapacityInMB);
        }
    }
}
```

To use the code:

```
private void btnRam_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RamCounter rc = new RamCounter();
    rc.GetRamSticks();
    MessageBox.Show(rc.ToString());
}
```

Sample output from my machine:

```
Description: Physical Memory
Location: J6H1
Format Factor: DIMM
Speed: 667
Capacity(MB): 1024

Description: Physical Memory
Location: J6H2
Format Factor: DIMM
Speed: 667
Capacity(MB): 1024

Description: Physical Memory
Location: J6J1
Format Factor: DIMM
Speed: 667
Capacity(MB): 1024

Total RAM(MB): 3072
```

Comment: This has the same problems as the `GlobalMemoryStatusEx` call.

Comment: Many of the properties state whether or not they are not supported in a particular version of Windows (or prior to a particular version). Neither of these properties I've mentioned state that they are only Vista or greater. That's not to say they are supported in XP though (haven't tried myself).

Comment: I suspect the calls inside Win32_ComputerSystem simply boil down to GlobalMemoryStatusEx calls. But the  Win32_PhysicalMemory enumeration should work on all systems. +1 for the update.

Answer (score 2):

I think WMI may give you this info ...

http://briandesmond.com/blog/getting-total-installed-memory-with-wmi/

Comment: Oooh -- wish I'd have thought of this. +1.

Comment: i'm not sure it it's xp friendly or not ... just thought I'd post it as an idea :-)

Answer (score 1):

One of the values returned by GlobalMemoryStatusEx is ullTotalPhys, which seems to be what you're looking for.

Things like ram used for video memory isn't in there, but I doubt there is a way to get to that at all.

Comment: Why is this answer being upvoted? It just restates the question in different words.